# i can't insert with multiple insert records

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I want to bring this information to insert multiple records from select

```
<?php
include_once("connect.inc.php");    

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$province_id = $_POST['province_id'][$i];
$province_id = $_POST['travel_id'][$i];

$i = 0;
foreach ( $_POST as $val) {


mysql_query("INSERT INTO travel_list (province_id, travel_id) VALUES ('$province_id', '$travel_id')");
$i++;
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="respond.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="post"> <!--ส่งค่า post ไปหน้าเดิม -->
<table width="896" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th width="239">จังหวัด</th>
<th width="552">สถานที่ท่องเที่ยว</th>
<th width="83"><input type="hidden" id="txtNum" value="1" size="2" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="239">
    <select id="selProvince" name="province_id[]"> <!--Default จังหวััด-->
        <option value="">กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด</option>
                <?PHP
                    $SelectPr="SELECT * FROM province";
                    $QueryPro=mysql_query($SelectPr);
                    while($Pro=mysql_fetch_array($QueryPro)){
                ?>
    <option value="<?=$Pro['province_id']?>"><?=$Pro['province_name']?></option>
<?PHP } ?>
</select>
</th>
<th width="552"><select name ="travel_id[]" id="selTravel"><option value="">กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด</option></select></th>
<th width="83"><button type="button" id="btnP">เพิ่มรายการ</button></th>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><center>รายการที่เพิ่ม</center></td></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

</tbody>

</table>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="add">

</form>




</body>
</html>
```

I'm insert 1 record  but I choose just one , but more data is imported into fifth data .

[image: view1]

[image: view2]

Please help me I solved this does not come for another three days.
Please help me Project BA Time remaining 1 day

Comment: This doesn't make sense - and it doesn't help us figure out your problem "Please help me I solved this does not come for another three days. Please help me Project BA Time remaining 1 day"

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the counter in the loop
but getting the first value only - outside the loop

Fix error in vars

```
$province_id = $_POST['province_id'][$i];
$travel_id = $_POST['travel_id'][$i];
```

remove loop and quotes

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO travel_list (province_id, travel_id) VALUES ($province_id, $travel_id)");
```

> EDIT - IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS

```
<?php
include_once("connect.inc.php");    

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $province_id = $_POST['province_id'];
    $travel_id = $_POST['travel_id'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO travel_list (province_id, travel_id) VALUES    ($province_id, $travel_id)");
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm insert 1 record but I choose just one , but more data is imported into fifth data .

Comment: please help me T_T  Please help me I solved this does not come for another three days. Please help me Project BA Time remaining 1 day

Comment: WHat does that mean? If you choose one - and insert one - what else would you like?

Comment: I want to add multiple Record. Add 1 record if it is to insert 1 record , but if 5 recoed data will insert 5 record. Sorry i'm not good english

Comment: Your form does not allow multiple selections - you can only select one province Id and one travel id

Comment: How To determine where  it To be able to add multiple record.

Comment: Sorry - none of this makes any sense - your table shows one provinceID and travelID per record - but if allow multiples you could have 5 provinces and 10 travelIDs. To allow multiple options elected - add multiple to your select element

Comment: I just want to pick just 1 province_id but travel_id can choose more than one .

Answer (score 0):

and i uses insert 3 record

[image: 3 record]

but  insert 1 record 
Just insert the data into one data remaining 0 0 0 0 .

[image: database]

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating just over $_POST['province id'], otherwise you run the loop through entire $_POST data that also include the hidden field, submit button, etc...

```
foreach ( $_POST['province_id'] as $province_id) {

$travel_id= $_POST['travel_id'][$i];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO travel_list (province_id, travel_id) VALUES ('$province_id', '$travel_id')");
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[bug insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQKVJ.png)

foreach ( $_POST as $val) {

```
$province_id = $_POST['province_id'][$i];
$travel_id= $_POST['travel_id'][$i];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO travel_list (province_id, travel_id) VALUES ('$province_id', '$travel_id')");
$i++;
```

}

I'm insert 1 record but I choose just one , but more data is imported into fifth data .

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBjeY.png)

Comment: I don't know why you even need a loop for $POST - you only have the two form fields and you've already assigned them

Comment: I want to add multiple Record. Add 1 record if it is to insert 1 record , but if 5 recoed data will insert 5 record. Sorry i'm not good english